# How to use LIKE operator in DB2 with values from another table?

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT  
    CASE  
        WHEN TYPES LIKE '%Linux%' THEN 'LINUX'
        WHEN TYPES LIKE '%Windows%' THEN 'WINDOWS'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'  
    END AS COMP,  
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL


FROM  
    COMPUTERS.OS



GROUP BY  
    CASE  
        WHEN TYPES LIKE '%Linux%' THEN 'LINUX'
        WHEN TYPES LIKE '%Windows%' THEN 'WINDOWS'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'  
END
```

It works flawlessly, but I need to take values (Linux, Windows) to fill LIKE...THEN statement from another table? How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
SELECT ot.comp, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM COMPUTERS.OS JOIN
     OtherTable ot
     ON types like ot.pattern
GROUP BY ot.comp;
```

This assumes that `othertable` has two columns, one is the pattern and the other is `comp`.

Comment: Wow, it works. But few questions? Does it require exact match? For example, it there are few OS in a cell? For example: Windows,Linux. And how can I add unknown type, which doesn't match any other types? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anatoly . . . You can use a `left join` to keep all the rows in `os`, regardless of whether they match, and then use this information as the "unknown" type.